# Python PyInstaller - Failed to execute script Error

Tags: python, pip, pyinstaller

I have a code, which i want to pack as an EXE. The package packs completely, but whenever i run it, it says

> Failed to execute script

My code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox as tmsg
import string
import random

root = Tk()

def helpf():
    tmsg.showinfo("How it works", "Enter the length of the password required\nThen select the strength of password\nClick the generate button to receive the password.\nClick on File->Save to Save the genrated Password")

def savefile():
    f=open('/Passwords.txt', 'a')
    f.write(pwd +'\n')
    f.close()

def password():
    global pwd 
    pwd=""   
    #pwd=str()
    #pwd=""
    value = str()
    if (Lengthvalue.get()>16) or (Lengthvalue.get()==""):
       Label(text="Please enter a correct password strength").grid(row=6,column=1) 
       
    if Weakvalue.get()==1:
        value = string.ascii_letters
    elif Moderatevalue.get()==1:
        value = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
    elif Strongvalue.get()==1:
        value = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + '!?@#'
    else:
       Label(text="Please select Password Strength").grid(row=6,column=1) 
    
    if value!=str():
        Label(text="                                                                 ").grid(row=6,column=1)
        for x in range(0,Lengthvalue.get()):
            pwd = pwd + random.choice(value)
        Label(text=pwd,font=("Goodtimes",10, "bold")).grid(row=6, column=1)
    
#def password():
    #print(Weakvalue, Moderatevalue, Strongvalue)
    
root.geometry("500x400")
root.minsize(500,400)
root.maxsize(500,400)
root.title("Random Password Generator")

#Heading
Label(text="Random Password Generator", bg="red", font=("Forte",15, "bold"),borderwidth=5, relief=RIDGE).grid(row=0, column=1)

#CheckBox
Lengthvalue=IntVar()
Weakvalue=IntVar()
Moderatevalue=IntVar()
Strongvalue=IntVar()

Label(text="Enter the length of\nPassword Required:\n(Between 8-16) ").grid(row=1, column=0)
Label(text="Select the Strength of\nPassword Required: ").grid(row=3, column=0)

Length=Entry(root, textvariable=Lengthvalue)
Weak=Checkbutton(text="Weak Password", variable=Weakvalue)
Moderate=Checkbutton(text="Moderate Password", variable=Moderatevalue)
Strong=Checkbutton(text="Strong Password", variable=Strongvalue)

Length.grid(row=1, column=1)
Weak.grid(row=3, column=1)
Moderate.grid(row=4, column=1)
Strong.grid(row=5, column=1)

#Generate Password Button
fr=Frame(root, borderwidth=3, bg="grey", relief=SUNKEN)
fr.grid(row=8, column=1)
b1=Button(fr, bg="white", text="Generate", command=password)
b1.grid(row=8, column=1)

#Adding Menus
mainmenu=Menu(root)

filemenu=Menu(mainmenu, tearoff=0)
filemenu.add_command(label="Save", command=savefile)
filemenu.add_separator()
filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=quit)
mainmenu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
root.config(menu=mainmenu)

helpmenu=Menu(mainmenu, tearoff=0)
helpmenu.add_command(label="How it works", command=helpf)
mainmenu.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=helpmenu)
root.config(menu=mainmenu)

root.mainloop()
```

It is a random password generator, and it creates and saves its answer in .txt file in the same directory.

Python version 3.60 (Downgraded it for pyinstaller to work)

Comment: please run this exe by going in your terminal by just changing directory where this exe is kept and then giving the name of exe. Tell me the output with the error statement.

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly! this thing works for me

you need to use this code

`pyinstaller password_generator.py --add-data passwords.txt`